# How to call a user defined function using the 'CALL' statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, call

I was going thru the Oracle documentation for the CALL statement.  It is indicated there that the CALL statement can be used to call a user defined function by using INTO (not a function inside a package).  I've tried loads of combinations but can't seem to get the right one.  Can someone give me an example on how to do this?  Thanks.

EDIT:

I've tried the example below in SQL Developer but i am getting an error.

```
variable x number; 
call f(10) into :x;
```

I'm getting a bang in line 2 and the error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound<br>
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
```

Comment: Please post what you tried and the problems you are having, so that people can help you to edit your code

Comment: `SELECT function_name(paramters)` This should work.

Comment: I have a scenario where a function performs a DML so i'm looking for other ways to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4009.htm#SQLRF01108):

```
VARIABLE x VARCHAR2(25);

CALL warehouse_typ(456, 'Warehouse 456', 2236).ret_name()
   INTO :x;
```

Another example:

```
create function f(n number) return number is
begin
    return n * 2;
end;

SQL> variable x number;
SQL> call f(10) into :x;

Call completed.

SQL> print x;

         X
----------
        20
```

Comment: Worth noting that if a function has no arguments for a call to be successful empty parenthesis are required: `call f1() into :var`

Comment: I'm trying to run your example in SQL developer but to no avail.  I'm getting this error:

SQL Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"

when running

variable x number;
call f(10) into :x;

it also shows a syntax error on line 2.

Thanks!